# jQuery $(this).html(text) doesn't work in a innested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm working to a script that could change text to show about the language that user choose.
Actually, I'm doing it on page load, with ita language on default. It works on all divs, except for innested div. I can't understand why, it doesn't raise exception, so neither try catch can say me why. This is my script:

```
var pattEng1 = /\[lang='eng']/g;
var pattEng2 = /\[.{1}lang='eng']/g;
var pattIta1 = /\[lang='ita']/g;
var pattIta2 = /\[.{1}lang='ita']/g;
var langs = ["ita","eng"];
var texts = new Array();
var i = 0, j;
var textToEdit, startPosEng, endPosEng;

$("div").each(function(){
    texts.push($(this).html());
    textToEdit =  texts[i];
    startPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng1) + 12;
    endPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng2) - startPosEng;
    textToEdit = textToEdit.replace(textToEdit.substr(startPosEng,endPosEng),"");
    try {
        $(this).html(textToEdit);
    }
    catch(err) {
       $("#demo").html(err.message);
    }
    j = 0;
    while(j < langs.length) {
        textToEdit = $(this).html();
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "");
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[\/lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "")
        $(this).html(textToEdit);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
});
```

I tried to "alert" textToEdit variable after the "replace" in innested div, and it works, it replaces what it has to replace, but it doesn't put it in $(this).html(textToEdit).
Thank you so much.
Here my HTML code:

```
<div>
[lang='eng']
CHAPTER ONE - 01<br>
THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
[lang='ita']
CAPITOLO UNO - 01<br>
IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 01b<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 01b<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 03<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 03<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 04<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 04<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 05<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 05<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
CHAPTER ONE - 06<br>
THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
Dudley mixing with a child like that.<br>
CAPITOLO UNO - 06<br>
IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` has different context at some places in your code. Better to cache it with a variable then use it:

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);   //<-----cache here
    texts.push($this.html()); // <----change here
    textToEdit =  texts[i];
    startPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng1) + 12;
    endPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng2) - startPosEng;
    textToEdit = textToEdit.replace(textToEdit.substr(startPosEng,endPosEng),"");
    try {
        $this.html(textToEdit); /// <-----here
    }
    catch(err) {
       $("#demo").html(err.message);
    }
    j = 0;
    while(j < langs.length) {
        textToEdit = $this.html(); // <----here
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "");
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[\/lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "")
        $this.html(textToEdit); ///<------and here
        j++;
    }
    i++;
});
```

Comment: there is an example yet! You can copy - paste my html code and js :)

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your code a little, now it seems to be working.

```js
var pattEng1 = /\[lang='eng']/g;
var pattEng2 = /\[.{1}lang='eng']/g;
var pattIta1 = /\[lang='ita']/g;
var pattIta2 = /\[.{1}lang='ita']/g;
var langs = ["ita","eng"];
var texts = new Array();
var i = 0;
var startPosEng, endPosEng;
var $div = $("div").filter(function(){return $(this).find("div").length ===0;});
$div.each(function(){
    texts.push($(this).html());
    var textToEdit =  texts[i];
    startPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng1) + 12;
    endPosEng = textToEdit.search(pattEng2) - startPosEng;
    textToEdit = textToEdit.replace(textToEdit.substr(startPosEng,endPosEng),"");
    try {
        $(this).html(textToEdit);
    }
    catch(err) {
       $("#demo").html(err.message);
    }
    var j = 0;
    while(j < langs.length) {
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "");
        textToEdit = textToEdit.replace("[\/lang='"+langs[j]+"']", "");
        j++;
    }
    texts[i] = textToEdit;
    
    i++;
});
 $("div").wrapAll( "<div class='result'/>").parents(".result").html(texts.join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
[lang='eng']
CHAPTER ONE - 01<br>
THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
[lang='ita']
CAPITOLO UNO - 01<br>
IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 01b<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a 
  big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 01b<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 03<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 03<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 04<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 04<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
    [lang='eng']
    CHAPTER ONE - 05<br>
    THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
    Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 05<br>
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div>
CHAPTER ONE - 06<br>
THE BOY WHO LIVED<br>
Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.<br>
Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.<br>
The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
Dudley mixing with a child like that.<br>
CAPITOLO UNO - 06<br>
IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO<br>
Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.<br>
Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.
</div>
```

er four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
    that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
    people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
    because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.
    Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
    drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
    have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
    nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
    spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
    opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.
    The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
    their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
    think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
    Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
    in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
    sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
    possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
    say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
    Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
    was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
    Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
    [lang='ita']
    CAPITOLO UNO - 01
    IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO
    Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
    perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
    avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.
    Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
    corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
    bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
    passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
    I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
    
        [lang='eng']
        CHAPTER ONE - 01b
        THE BOY WHO LIVED
        Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
        that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
        people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
        because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.
        Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
        drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
        have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
        nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
        spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
        neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
        opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.
        The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
        their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
        think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
        Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
        in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
        sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
        possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
        say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
        Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
        was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
        Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
        [lang='ita']
        CAPITOLO UNO - 01b
        IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO
        Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
        perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
        avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.
        Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
        corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
        bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
        passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
        I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
    
    
    
    
        [lang='eng']
        CHAPTER ONE - 03
        THE BOY WHO LIVED
        Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
        that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
        people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
        because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.
        Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
        drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
        have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
        nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
        spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
        neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
        opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.
        The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
        their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
        think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
        Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
        in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
        sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
        possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
        say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
        Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
        was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
        Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
        [lang='ita']
        CAPITOLO UNO - 03
        IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO
        Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
        perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
        avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.
        Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
        corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
        bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
        passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
        I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']
    
    
    
        [lang='eng']
        CHAPTER ONE - 04
        THE BOY WHO LIVED
        Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were proud to say
        that they were perfectly normal, thank you very much. They were the last
        people you'd expect to be involved in anything strange or mysterious,
        because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.
        Mr. Dursley was the director of a firm called Grunnings, which made
        drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly any neck, although he did
        have a very large mustache. Mrs. Dursley was thin and blonde and had
        nearly twice the usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she
        spent so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
        neighbors. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudley and in their
        opinion there was no finer boy anywhere.
        The Dursleys had everything they wanted, but they also had a secret, and
        their greatest fear was that somebody would discover it. They didn't
        think they could bear it if anyone found out about the Potters. Mrs.
        Potter was Mrs. Dursley's sister, but they hadn't met for several years;
        in fact, Mrs. Dursley pretended she didn't have a sister, because her
        sister and her good-for-nothing husband were as unDursleyish as it was
        possible to be. The Dursleys shuddered to think what the neighbors would
        say if the Potters arrived in the street. The Dursleys knew that the
        Potters had a small son, too, but they had never even seen him. This boy
        was another good reason for keeping the Potters away; they didn't want
        Dudley mixing with a child like that.[/lang='eng']
        [lang='ita']
        CAPITOLO UNO - 04
        IL RAGAZZO SOPRAVVISSUTO
        Mr e Mrs Dursley, di Privet Drive numero 4, erano orgogliosi di poter affermare che erano
        perfettamente normali e grazie tante. Erano le ultime persone al mondo da cui aspettarsi che
        avessero a che fare con cose strane o misteriose, perché sciocchezze del genere proprio non le approvavano.
        Mr Dursley era direttore di una ditta di nome Grunnings, che fabbricava trapani. Era un uomo
        corpulento, nerboruto, quasi senza collo e con un grosso paio di baffi. Mrs Dursley era magra,
        bionda e con un collo quasi due volte più lungo del normale, il che le tornava assai utile, dato che
        passava gran parte del tempo ad allungarlo oltre la siepe del giardino per spiare i vicini.
        I Dursley avevano un figlioletto di nome Dudley e secondo loro non esisteva al mondo un bambino più bello.[/lang='ita']

Comment: It doesn't work neither with 2.1.1 (I'm running 3.1) and neither if I use "Run code snippet" TT_____TT

Comment: It doesn't work still... I can't understand why in console.log and in alert print right text, but it doesn't put right text in $this.html(textToEdit)...

Comment: sorry, give me a few mins

Comment: @ProtoTyPus, Amico , I have debugged every line of your codes, now it is finally fixed. Please run the snippet.